# Get Drive File Link Using Python

Tags: python, google-drive-api, data-science, drive

I have many audio files in one folder and I want links of that files and want to paste into the data frame, for one file it's possible to copy the link, but there are 10000 files, so is there any code to automate this in python ?

[Click for the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/apaZ3.png)

Comment: In your situation, the folder is publicly shared? Or, the folder is not publicly shared and you are the owner of the folder?

Comment: I'm the owner of the folder

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, unfortunately, I couldn't understand whether your folder is publicly shared. If your folder is publicly shared, your goal can be achieved by a simple script. But if your folder is not publicly shared, the access token is required to be used. In this case, [this document](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/python) might be useful.

Answer (score 2):

You Could Always use pyautogui and manually adjust it if you dont know how to use it just refer to this https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/mouse-keyboard-automation-using-python/ and then if the drive link is copied to clipboard just add the pyperclip module and then  `link = pyperclip.paste() print(link)`
**I guess this answers!**

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
d = "dir"
for path in os.listdir(d):
    full_path = os.path.join(d, path)
    if os.path.isfile(full_path):
        print full_path
```

Enter the directory you want to search and then replace the print with your code to add them. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I don't want path of the file but I want URL  (link) of the specific drive file.